# Desktop went to sleep during release upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.10, suspend

Every post I see here is either a laptop, or somebody who restarted their computer whilst asleep mid-upgrade. My case is neither.

So I started a release upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10, some 10 hours ago. around 30 minutes into it, my monitor went to sleep. Neither moving the mouse or hitting any key on the keyboard has any effect, however the computer is still running.

10 hours is a bit past the high side for how long an upgrade takes, Would it be slower if it's running in sleep mode? When, if ever will it be safe to hold the power down and force a reboot?

Please advise.

Comment: Bug reports and feature requests should be made on [LaunchPad](https://launchpad.net/), we are just volunteers here, we can't do anything with bug reports or feature requests.

Comment: Did it go to sleep when it was downloading the updates or when it was actually installing them?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda It went to sleep while installing the upgrades. I knew it could take a very long while so I stepped away from the computer, when it was asleep an hour later, I decided to just go to bed and check on it in the morning, assuming it would reboot when it was finished.